# Return Original datatype after LINQ group by

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need my LINQ Query to return the Product Datatype, after being grouped. It seems to be encased into an anonymous psuedo family.

I have some properties in Product that I don't care about, just needing the p.ID and p.Name etc.

The error I'm getting at the moment with this is:

```
The entity or complex type 'DatabaseModel.Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

This is my Method:

```
        public static List<Product> GetSellableSpecialOffers(DatabaseEntities db)
    {

        var query = from p in db.Products
                    where (p.Visible == true && p.Active == true)
                    && p.ShowInSpecialOffers == true
                    group p by p.FamilyID == null ? 0 : p.FamilyID into f
                    select new Product {
                    ID = f.First().ID,
                    Name = f.First().Name,
                    Cost = f.First().Cost,
                    RRP = f.First().RRP
                    };

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

What is the problem? Is there a better way around this? SQL would always return 1 record instead of encasing the object in a secondary datatype, I don't get it.

Many thanks,

**EDIT 1:**

My apologies for extending the specification, but I need the returned product to be programatically generated e.g.

```
select new Product {
                    ID = f.First().ID,
                    Name = f.First().Name,
                    Cost = f.OrderBy(p => p.NowCost).FirstOrDefault(),
                    RRP = f.First().RRP
                    }
```

*or* if I could strongly type the family class:

```
    public partial class ProductFamily
{
    public Product GroupedProduct 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Products.OrderBy(p => p.NowCost).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would do:

```
 var query = (from p in db.Products
                    where (p.Visible == true && p.Active == true)
                    && p.ShowInSpecialOffers == true
                    group p by p.ProductFamily == null ? null : p.ProductFamily into f
                     select f.GroupedProduct).ToList<Product>();
```

But I can't get either solution to work with what I have.

Comment: Any reason you don't just take `f.First()`? You may not *need* the properties, but do you explicitly need to remove them?

Comment: Please post your Product class

Comment: It's an entity framework auto gen class

Comment: you wan't be able to use GroupedProduct in a linq to entities query. You can use only properties existing in db, and a property without setter won't exist in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try (boring, but not sure you have the choice)

```
var query = from p in db.Products
                    where (p.Visible == true && p.Active == true)
                    && p.ShowInSpecialOffers == true
                    group p by p.FamilyID == null ? 0 : p.FamilyID into f
                    select new {
                    ID = f.First().ID,
                    Name = f.First().Name,
                    Cost = f.OrderBy(m => m.NowCost).First().Cost,
                    RRP = f.First().RRP
                    };

return query.ToList().Select(m => 
new Product {
    ID = m.ID,
    Name = m.Name, 
    Cost = m.Cost,
    RRP = m.RRP
};
```

**EDIT** 
Or as pointed by Master Skeet (not exactly the same as what you tried, but much easier)

```
var query = from p in db.Products
                    where (p.Visible == true && p.Active == true)
                    && p.ShowInSpecialOffers == true
                    group p by p.FamilyID == null ? 0 : p.FamilyID into f
                    select f.OrderBy(m => m.NowCost).First();
```

Comment: Won't this just un-group my initial results?

Comment: @Smithy With the first version of your edit, of course (do it in the first part of my first solution will be ok). The "strongly typed" version of  your edit won't work in linq to entities...

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I think I'm going to store the cheapest variation of a products family in the database (on each product) to save some overhead but this is the best and most comprehensive answer. thanks again :)

Comment: @Smithy ina fact your "edited" code wouldn't work as is, I edited my answer with your new need.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply `select f.First()` and return the resulting data, like this:

```
var query = from p in db.Products
            where (p.Visible == true && p.Active == true)
            && p.ShowInSpecialOffers == true
            group p by p.FamilyID == null ? 0 : p.FamilyID into f
            select f.First();
```

Then outside the method use whatever properties you need, ignoring what you don't care about (you *are* handling `Product` objects, properties *should* be there even if you don't need them).

Comment: Jon Skeet landed it first but this is nearly the correct answer.
I need to reconstruct my product so I can work out the cheapest price, the default image etc...

Comment: Oh you're right, I missed his comment. Still, my point is more along the lines of "you don't need to drop properties, take them along and simply ignore them".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word 'Product' from

```
select new Product{}
```

'select new' itself will create an anonymous type whereas you are specifying it as a Product.

Comment: It won't infer the type. It will create an anonymous type, which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: In particular, you won't be able to return it as a `List<Product>`

Comment: Yeah, I'm explicitly casting it now on the return:
            return (List<Product>)query;
Still didn't fix though :(